# Algo hizo que me dejara de aparecer el botón guardar

Tags: php, html, botón

Hola a todos recién estoy iniciando en esto de la programación.
Intentando arreglar otra cosa, nose que paso que el botón de guardar y la linea de copyright del final ya no las veo en la interfaz.
Revise todos los  creo que están bien.
Alguna idea de que otra cosa puede ser?
Seguro sea una pavada pero ya me volví loca buscando.
Es codigo html para cargar materiales en una base de dato, al principio me aparecia bien el botón guardar pero nose en que momento fue que deje de verlo.
Dejo abajo el cogigo de esta pagina pero en la que es para modificar los materiales me paso lo mismo, copie todo porque nose si es sintaxys de HTML el problema o alguna referencia que capas no esta bien.
Gracias

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.0.1">
    <title>Ejemplo - Materiales</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/checkout/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../js/form-validation.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
 <div class="py-5 text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"><h2>
        <img border="0" src="../img/atras.png" width="48" height="48" title="Volver al menú"
        onclick=location.href='../materiales/'; onKeyPress=location.href='../materiales/'; style='cursor:pointer';/>
    </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><img class="d-block mx-auto mb-1" src="../img/logo.png" alt="" width="62" height="62"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><h2>Ejemplo</h2></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-12 order-md-1">
      <h4 class="mb-4">Alta Materiales</h4>
      <form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="grabar.php" method="post">

<?php
    require "../conexion.php";

        $sql = "SELECT * from materiales order by lugarmat";
      $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
      while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $materiales[] = $resultado;
        }

?>



        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
            <label for="nombremat">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombremat" name="nombremat" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Faltó ingresar el nombre.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 mb-4">
            <label for="preciomat">¿Precio? (Enteros, decimales)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="preciomat" name="preciomat" placeholder="" value="" >
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
          <label for="tipo">ID Lugar:</label>
          <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="lugarmat" name="lugarmat" required>
       <?php
       $long = count($materiales);
       for($i=0; $i< $long; $i++){
       echo "<option";
              if($materiales[$i]['lugarmat']== $materiales[0]['lugarmat']){
                  echo " selected ";}
              echo " value=" .$materiales[$i]['lugarmat'];
              echo ">" .$materiales[$i]['lugarmat'];
              echo "</option> ";}
      ?>
        </div>
            </div>
    <!-- --------------------->
  *</div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-ms" type="submit">Guardar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
    <p class="mb-1">&copy; 2020 - Ejemplo</p>*

  </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="../js/form-validation.js"></script></body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, tienes muchas etiquetas que no cierran donde deberían. En Firefox sitúate en tu proyecto y presiona Win+U para visualizar el código fuente de tu página para que te des una idea clara de dónde estén los posibles errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Gracias. No conocía ese truco, claramente no se nada! Logre que funcione otra vez.